# Custom MembershipProvider attempts to pass empty creds after IIS restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I have a C# custom ASP.Net MembershipProvider.  When the user attempts to navigate to another part of the site after IIS is restarted, it doesn't navigate to the login page to collect credentials, but instead attempts to authenticate with empty credentials.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do to identify that the new authentication needs to take place and that new creds need to be gathered?

I have a complementary custom IHttpModule implementation that allows me to intercept events like BeginRequest and AuthenticateRequest, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

did you override the mandatory functions from MembershipProvider?  Do you know if MembershipProvider.ValidateUser() is being passed empty credentials or not?  As if that method is still getting called, it'd be simple to check there.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond to this question.  No code in the Membership Provider seems to be executed after the IIS restart.  Keep in mind, the user successfully logged in BEFORE the IIS restart.

Comment: do you have any cookie operations happening that may be trying to do a login for the users?